# Convert code to python list comprehension

Tags: python

Code like that:

```
class H:
    def __init__(self, row):
        self.row = row

    @staticmethod
    def gg(word):
        if not word:
            return 0
        return 1

    def ff(self):
        l = []                         # return [sentence for sentence in self.row.split('/') for word in self.gg(sentence.split(' '))]
        for sentence in self.row.split('/'):
            num_of_syllables = 0
            for word in sentence.split(' '):
                num_of_syllables += self.gg(word)
            l.append(num_of_syllables)
        return l
```

Is it possible to shorten above coe and use to list comprehension in function ff()?

```
return [sentence for sentence in self.row.split('/') for word in self.gg(sentence.split(' '))]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One very useful thing for counting truthy values like this is the fact that `bool` is a subclass of `int`, `True == 1` and `False == 0`

```
def ff(self):
    return [
        sum(bool(word) for word in sentence.split(' '))
        for sentence in self.row.split('/')
    ]
```